# Elastic line equation in Matlab - Error using Mupadengine/feval - Error in dsolve>mupadDsolve - Error in dsolve

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, differential-equations

I can't understand the solution of multiple differential equations in Matlab. In this example, I'm trying to work with independent equations: the program should solve them separately (and it does, see below) and together (it doesn't!), shouldn't it?

<sub>N.B. The equations describe the elastic line according to Euler Bernoulli. I'd like to use them, just setting the appropriate intitial conditions and known data for each problem.</sub>

This is the part of code in common with both procedures:

Creating symbolic functions

```
syms v(z) w(z)
syms B Chiterm p mx by l A Eterm p bz
```

Differentiating

```
D1v = diff(v,z);
D2v = diff(v,z,2);
D3v = diff(v,z,3);
D4v = diff(v,z,4);
D1w = diff(w,z);
D2w = diff(w,z,2);
```

Setting known values (and parameters, like `p`)

```
by=-p;
Chiterm=0;
mx=0
bz=0;
Eterm=0
```

Defining differential equations

```
odetrasv = diff(B*(diff(v,z,2)+Chiterm),z,2)-mx-by == 0;
odelong = diff(A*(diff(w,z)-Eterm),z)+bz == 0;
```

Defining initial conditions

```
cond1 = B*D2v(l) == 0;
cond2 = D1v(0) == 0;
cond3 = v(0) == 0;
cond4 = v(l) == 0;
cond5 = D1w(l) == 0;
cond6 = w(0) == 0;
```

Here is the part of the code that solves the equations separately:

```
condstrasv = [cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4];
condslong = [cond5 cond6];
vSol(z) = dsolve(odetrasv, condstrasv);
wSol(z) = dsolve(odelong, condslong);
vSol = simplify(vSol)
wSol = simplify(wSol)
```

Here's the part that is not working. I'm trying to solve them togheter, since the next step is solving a system of multiple equations:

```
odes = [odetrasv; odelong];
conds = [cond1; cond2; cond3; cond4; cond5; cond6];
[vSol(z), wSol(z)] = dsolve(odes,conds)
```

Matlab returns:

> Error using Mupadengine/feval - Invalid initial conditions 
>   Error in dsolve>mupadDsolve - T=feval(symengine,'symobj::dsolve',sys....
>   Error in dsolve - sol = mupadDsolve(args, options);

Why are the initial conditions invalid in the second case? Solving without them works:

```
[vSol(z), wSol(z)] = dsolve(odes)
```

Comment: I can replicate this in R2017b. You don't appear to be doing anything wrong and I think that this ought to work. The issue may be due to the fact that this isn't a coupled system of differential equations so `dsolve` may get confused when checking the initial conditions. I don't know of a workaround other than to solve the equations independently. I suggest that you [file a service request](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html) with the MathWorks on this.